# Why the items in all the rows of row list are getting repeated in brightscript

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am trying to use rowlist which contain 3 rows. Each row will contain 11 items. But when it is getting displayed, after 11 items, again items are getting repeated in all the rows.

Below are the XML files.

**BrowseScreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<component name="BrowseScreen" extends="Group">
    <children>
        <!-- The main content -->
        <RowList id="BrowseRowList"
            itemComponentName="customItem"
            focusXOffset="[0]"
            itemSize="[1920,500]"
            numRows="3"
            drawFocusFeedback="false"
            rowFocusAnimationStyle="fixedFocusWrap"
            rowHeights="[500]"
            showRowLabel="[true]"
            rowLabelOffset="[[0,20]]"
            rowItemSpacing="[[0,40]]"
            showRowCounter="[false]"
            rowItemSize="[[250,273]]"
            variableWidthItems="[true]"
            translation="[70, 40]" />

    </children>

    <script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/BrowseScreen/BrowseScreen.brs"/>
</component>
```

**customItem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<component name="customItem" extends="Group">
    <children>
        <Group id="itemCard" translation="[10, 10]" scale="[0.90, 0.90]"
               scaleRotateCenter="[125.0, 183.0]">

            <Poster id="itemPoster" 
                width="250"
                height="375"
                failedBitmapUri="pkg:/images/placeholder/iptv_placeholder_2by3_dark.png"
                loadingBitmapUri="pkg:/images/placeholder/iptv_placeholder_2by3_dark.png"
                loadDisplayMode="scaleToZoom" />

            <Group id="itemMetaGroup" 
                visible="false" 
                translation="[0, 273]">

                <Rectangle id="itemMetaBG" 
                    width="364"
                    height="102"
                    color="0x333333" />

                <Label id="itemMetaLabel" 
                    width="320" 
                    height="55" 
                    color="0xebebeb" 
                    opacity="1.0"
                    translation="[20, 20]" 
                    horizAlign="left">
                    <Font role="font" uri="pkg:/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf" size="21" />
                </Label>

                <Label id="itemMetaData" 
                    width="320" 
                    height="55"
                    text="{MetaData}" 
                    color="0x959595" 
                    opacity="1.0"
                    translation="[20, 60]" 
                    horizAlign="left">
                    <Font role="font" uri="pkg:/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf" size="21" />
                </Label>            
            </Group>
        </Group>

    </children>

    <script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/Item/customItem.brs" />
    <script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/Utils/itemType.brs" />
</component>
```

If I have 11 posters in each row, it is getting displayed as below

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 1 2 ...

I am unable to understand why the items are getting repeated. Can anyone please let me know if there is any way to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RowList is behaving as such because its rowFocusAnimationStyle is set to "fixedFocusWrap". Changing it to `rowFocusAnimationStyle="floatingFocus"` should fix your problem.

Comment: changing rowFocusAnimationStyle="floatingFocus" doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: It doesn't effect because I am using variableWidthItems="[true]". If I remove this and use rowFocusAnimationStyle="floatingFocus", the problem is getting solved. But the items in a same row may have different widths. So I need to use fixedFocusWrap as variable widths can be supported by fixedFocusWrap only. Is there any way to fix this.

Comment: I consider of using postergrid for this. But I need to draw a line after each row. So I haven't used postergrid.